# JQuery: referring to the right "this"

Tags: jquery, this

I'm trying to write a very simple plugin that on anchor mouseover increases the respective anchor text size and on mouseout removes the anchor. The problem is that I can't get the right "this". So I have:

```
    (function($){
 $.fn.extend({
  //function name
  textOverlay : function(){
  //return
  return this.each(function(){
   var cucu = $(this);
   $(this).hover(
    function(){
     cucu.css({'font-size':'20px'});
    },
    function(){
     cucu.remove();
    }
   );
  }); 
  }
 });
})(jQuery);
```

and I call it like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
 $('a').thiseOverlay();
});
```

I guess I should use something like `.call()` or `.apply()`, but I'm not sure how, I couldn't find good resources.

Comment: The name of your plugin is textOverlay but in your example you're using thiseOverlay as the plugin name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work if you simply call `$('a').textOverlay()` instead of `$('a').thiseOverlay()` what you did.

Comment: i miss-typed when i wrote the code, but just in here cause i tried to simplify the code and i forgot to modify that. so in my real code i called it right : $('a').textOverlay(), and it doesn't work.

Comment: pfiu...now it works, but i don't know what was the problem. maybe i forgot to refresh the page :D thanks, sorry for this dumb question :)